# SpringBoot doesn't create table on MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, mysql-workbench

I created some classes in one package `uniroma3.siw.model` and the main is in other package `uniroma3.siw.progetto`. The project compile and doesn't generate any error but in MySQL Workbench tables aren't created.

This is one of entities that I have created:

```
@Entity
public class Admin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nome;

}
```

I didn't change the main, and this is the `application.proprieties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/progetto? 
serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: _Small Note: Terminology_ WorkBench is a tool and not a database. Tables exist in a database and MySQL is the DBMS in this question

Comment: Try change to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` or `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` . Let's tell me the result after that.

Comment: Move your main to `uniroma3.siw` as suggested as a best practice by the Spring Boot team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible causes for this:

- The `Admin` class is not in the same or sub-package as your Application. The solution to this problem would be to annotate your Application with `@EntityScan( basePackages = {"uniroma3.siw.model"} )`
- The `application.properties` file is not in the correct location. It should be located in `src/main/resources`

Comment: thanks a lot, i resolved this problem adding @EntityScan(...)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! It was very easy.

```
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"it.uniroma3.siw.model"} )
```

it was enough to add this line to the main after @SpringBootApplication

Comment: This is because your main is in a different package. The Spring Boot team advices to put your main (the `@SpringBOotApplication` annotated class) in a apckage that spans everything. That way you don't have to do things like this `@EntityScan`.